# Wordpress + Bootstrap - data-toggle="collapse" not working in Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap 3 and am trying to build a wordpress-theme for my company.
I've got everything running fine on OS-X in Firefox and Safari, but Google Chrome is giving me some headaches.

I'm using the navbar and some collapsed content on several pages. In Google Chrome the "data-toggle" and the navbar-button (mobile) is only firing in one way and then it is stuck. The Developer-Tool is not showing any issus.

The link to the wordpress site: http://dev.das-werbewerk.de/
And a link to a page with the collapsed content: http://dev.das-werbewerk.de/katalog-marketing/

Anybody here, who can help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Timo

Comment: It's working good for me, Chrome 59/Win764 (I can open and close collapsible elements). Maybe try hard refresh (CTRL+SHIFT+R).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had installed Chrome 58 so I updated to v59. It's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Updated Chrome and now it's working fine. Problem solved!